# Facebook authentication isn't working using devise+omniauth facebook(except Admin user or test user)

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise, omniauth

I'm using devise and omniauth facebook for user authentication in my rails 4.1 app. User authentication is perfectly working with admin user and test user of facebook. But the problem is when I am trying to signin with other facebook user, it is failed to create a new user and redirecting me at localhost:3000/users/sign_up#*=*. I've also uploaded the project at heroku but I'm getting the same problem.

Here is devise.rb

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "App_ID", "App_Secret"
```

route.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

User.rb Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if user
      return user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        return registered_user
      else
        user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                            provider:auth.provider,
                            uid:auth.uid,
                            email:auth.info.email,
                            first_name:auth.info.first_name,
                            last_name:auth.info.last_name,
                            image:auth.info.image,
                            location:auth.extra.raw_info.location,
                            gender:auth.extra.raw_info.gender,
                            oauth_token:auth.credentials.token,
                            password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                          )
      end

    end
  end

  def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
  end
end
```

Omniauth_call_back_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController   
    def facebook
        @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
end
```

View file:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

Comment: Which permissions do you request?

Comment: I have permissions for public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_education_history and user_birthday.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this isn't working because you need to pass the review of your app by FB when you want to use extended permissions with other users than the app's admins/developers/testers

Have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've already passed the permission by fb.

Comment: I've also done that from "status and review" menu of fb.